# Phpunit test suites are not running

Tags: laravel, phpunit, codeship

I've an issue with

```
php vendor/bin/phpunit
```

I don't know why when I tried to run with codeship or bitbucket pipelines it seems wasn't run the test suites as follow:

```
php vendor/bin/phpunit
dir=$(cd "${0%[/\\]*}" > /dev/null; cd "../phpunit/phpunit" && pwd)
if [ -d /proc/cygdrive ] && [[ $(which php) == $(readlink -n /proc/cygdrive)/* ]]; then
   # We are in Cgywin using Windows php, so the path must be translated
   dir=$(cygpath -m "$dir");
fi
"${dir}/phpunit" "$@"
```

Perhaps someone could give me a thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

First recommendation would be to test out an [ssh debug session](https://documentation.codeship.com/basic/builds-and-configuration/ssh-access/), failing that you may want to reach out directly to support@codeship.com with your build url.